# Mobile website or a mobile app

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch-2, mobile-application, mobile-website

I want to make a mobile website which can use mobile native elements like camera, contacts and geolocation.

Can I make such website or I have to go for Mobile App ?

If Mobile App and consider Sencha Touch with PhoneGap, Is there any other option to distribute than going through app store ?

Will that work to build complete application using Sencha Touch and then wrap using PhoneGap to support all mobile devices ?

Do I need Mac machine or I can do everything using Windows ?

Comment: Asked thousands of times (native vs web apps) http://www.wired.com/insights/2012/11/native-apps-vs-mobile-web/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mobile browsers are getting better and better but there is likely that some functionality is available only on the native side. For example, geolocation is available on iOS for a while but access to camera is new in iOS6. So, you have to investigate yourself which functionality you need and if it is available on the target device.

You cannot distribute mobile apps without the app stores (at large scale at least).

In principle yes, but "support all mobile devices" is a bit vague and ambitious...

If all can be implemented without plugins, you can use any OS and build the app using PhoneGap Build service.

Answer (score 4):

When building with Sencha Touch or other "hybrid" technologies, you are dependent on HTML5. So some of your requirements cannot be meet by a HTML5 website that would support across the range of mobile devices.

Camera access: Currently HTML Media Capture is in draft with the W3C (http://www.w3.org/TR/html-media-capture/). This works on iOS 6+ not sure about Android, Blackberry or Window's phones. So, currently a HTML5 app wrapped in PhoneGap/Cordova would be your best solution so you can access the camera from the supported devices.

Contact access: You will need PhoneGap/Cordova for access to the devices contact list.

Geolocation: Available with HTML5 (http://html5demos.com/geo). No need for PhoneGap. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.device.Geolocation

If you want to cover current devices (iOS 5 to iOS 6+, Android 2.3+, Blackberry and Windows) you need to stay focused on building a hybrid app using some of the following technologies: HTML5 responsive design, JQuery Mobile, Sencha Touch and Titanium Appcelator. There are some other technologies out there but these seem to be the main stream for now.

Distribution of your application for testing can be done via testflight.com for iOS. If you do not want to go the Apple app store route you will need to look into an enterprise license with Apple which has quite a few stipulations. For Android, you can provide users with the .apk file and they can install it. This all depends on your environment. If you are building for a corporate controlled environment where your know your users and devices you have some options. If you are building to distribute to the world...Apple App Store and the Google Play Market is what you will need to use.

Do you need a Mac? Yes, if you are building iOS mobile applications and want to be able to test in a simulator and generate signed builds.

Answer (score 0):

There is a platform for websites that it is easy to install apps.

There are 2 cool apps that handles mobile sites with just a few clicks:

http://siteapps.com/app/mobile_site-321

and

http://siteapps.com/app/mobile_site_for_restaurants-447

Hope this can help.